# How to combine list of Completable tasks into one Completable result?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android, rx-java2, reactivex

I have a method that returns a `Single<List<Item>>`, and I would like to take each item in this list and pass it downstream to a method that returns `Completable`. I want to wait until each item has successfully completed and return a `Completable` result. My initial approach was to process each item separately using `flatMapIterable` and combine the results using `toList`, but I cannot call `toList` on a `Completable` object. Is there any other way to "aggregate" many `Completable` tasks into a single `Completable` in this fashion? Here's what I have so far:

```
public Single<List<Item>> getListOfItems() {
    ...
}

public Completable doSomething(Item item) {
    ...
}

public Completable processItems() {
    return getListOfItems()     
        .toObservable()
        .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
        .flatMapCompletable(item -> doSomething(item))
        .toList()    // ERROR: No method .toList() for Completable
        .ignoreElements();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `flatMapCompletable` operator do the trick, you don't need to apply additional operators further.

From the docs:

> Maps each element of the upstream Observable into CompletableSources, subscribes to them and waits until the upstream and all CompletableSources complete.

`flatMapCompletable` will return `Completable` that will complete when all mapped Completables complete their operation:

```
 public Completable processItems() {
    return getListOfItems()
            .toObservable()
            .flatMapIterable(items -> items)
            .flatMapCompletable(item -> doSomething(item));
}
```

Comment: I see, somehow I was misinterpreting what the docs were saying. Thanks a lot!